# IIS and external client-side resources failure time

Tags: iis, client-side

I have a website hosted on [iis](/questions/tagged/iis). The website has remote images in its contents some of those images becomes unavailable. i.e their website become down or they prevent leeching.

I got a jQuery script that replace any unavailable image with a default image.

My problem is: the website takes very long time waiting response from the other website, so the replace script works too late.

Is there any way makes [iis](/questions/tagged/iis) tell the client -the browser- to reduce the time of waiting the response?

I have tried to configure > limits in [iis](/questions/tagged/iis) and set the Connection timeout (in seconds) to be 30 but still I have the same long time?

Is there any thing using meta tags or http to solve this issue?